# Why isn't my deleteNode function working?

Tags: c, function, struct, linked-list

For some reason this function only works when I want to delete the first or last node, but crashes the program when I try something in the middle. Any suggestions/ideas to why this is happening?

```
void deleteNode(int partNumber)
{
    struct Inventory *prev;
    prev=first;

    if(prev==NULL)
        printf("\nError! No node!");
    else if(first->partNum==partNumber)
        first=first->next;
    else {
        while(prev!=NULL)
        {
            if(prev->next->partNum==partNumber)
            {
                prev->next=prev->next->next;
            }
            prev=prev->next;
        }
    }
}

printf("\nPlease enter the part number of what you would like to delete: ");//main
scanf("%d", &partDelete);
deleteNode(partDelete);
```

Answer (score 1):

You dereference a null pointer right here:

```
 if(prev->next->partNum==partNumber)
```

At this point `prev` is definitely valid but `prev->next` might be NULL.